# Dart DevTools give an error when enabling in VSCode - Dart DevTools exited with code 65

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-test

When I try to enable Dart DevTools I end up with the following error in VSCode.

```
Dart DevTools exited with code 65
```

I have already followed these two.

1. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28545
2. https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/2092
3. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/overview

How can I fix this error?

Comment: facing the same issue .. `devtools 0.1.5 doesn't support Dart 2.1.2` says my log, which is pretty straightforward

Comment: I'm using Dart VM version: 2.3.2 (Tue Jun 11 15:29:47 2019 +0200) on "macos_x64"

Comment: What happens if you run "pub global run devtools" from the terminal?

Comment: i having a very similar error Dart DevTools exited with code 255

Answer (score 3):

make this command

```
flutter pub cache repair
flutter pub cache add devtools
flutter pub cache repair
flutter pub global activate devtools
flutter pub global run devtools (to check it is working)
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally fixed this problem by deleting stuff in my .pub-cache directory that was in my home directory and not in my source directory.  I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: This solution is worked for me ✅

Answer (score 0):

For me Ctrl+Shift+P → Clear Editor History helped