# Dart DevTools exited with code 65 Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

While I'm trying to open the `Dart: Open DevTools` following error is coming. What may be the issue? and how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Try deleting the `pubspec.lock` file on that path.

Comment: No use I already tried it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dart DevTools give an error when enabling in VSCode - Dart DevTools exited with code 65](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57625136/dart-devtools-give-an-error-when-enabling-in-vscode-dart-devtools-exited-with)